# Validation issues in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following function is supposed to check two inputs: name and message. I'm not sure what is wrong here but I'm trying to first see if the input is empty if it's not I want to then check it with a regular expression.

The message I just want to see if it is empty or not. If either are empty I want to return a message asking to enter the correct input. I'm not sure if I should use else ifs here or separate if statements altogether. If I'm doing this completely bonkers Id like to know that as well.

JavaScript:

```
function validate() {
  let regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;
  let name = document.querySelector("[name='user-name']");
  let msg = document.querySelector("[name='user-message']");
  
  if (name) {
      name = name.value;   
  } else if (!regName.test(name)){
    document.querySelector("[name='user-name']");
    return "Please enter your first & last name.";    
  }

  if (msg) {
      msg = msg.value;
  } else if (msg.trim() == "") {     
    document.querySelector("[name='user-message']");
    return "Please enter a message";
  } 
}
```

Comment: Isn't any person's name "valid" no matter how its spelled? I could go to court tomorrow and change my name to `c++` if I wanted to. ... So do you need to check on validity of someone's "name" other it not being an empty string, stripped of all white space?

Comment: well, im trying to check for a first and lastg name, yes you could legally do that but if you had to enter your info into a form how would that work?

Comment: You're only doing `regName.test(name)` if the `user-name` input can't be found. Why do you have that code in `else if`?

Comment: The form will accept whatever name I entered. Ideally. But if you want non-outlier cases, you can always have a "lookup" table of common last names. The first name is all bets off.

Comment: I didnt know how to do both checks together

Comment: Why do you think you need the first check at all? Why would `querySelector()` fail to find an input you know is in the form?

Comment: I dont know thats why Im here if I knew these answers I wouldnt have this issue. Im just trying to check if these two inputs have values if not I want to tell the user they need to enter something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` and `else if` logic is wrong. You're only performing the regexp test when the input element can't be found by `document.querySelector()`. `else if` only runs when the previous condition failed.

You should put that check in the same `if` that checks that the input was found.

```js
function validate() {
  let regName = /^[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$/;
  let name = document.querySelector("[name='user-name']");
  let msg = document.querySelector("[name='user-message']");

  if (name && !regName.test(name.value)) {
    return "Please enter your first & last name.";
  }

  if (msg && msg.value.trim() == "") {
    return "Please enter a message";
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I had tried this already but I didnt have the .value attached to the second condition, That is why I broke it down to separate if statements. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: You could also do it with separate variables, but those lines should be inside the `if` block, right after you assign `name = name.value;`. Not in `else if`. Just think about what the word "else" means in English.